# Can I use FFTW to make transform along first and last axis of 3D array?

Tags: fft, fftw

Using `fftw_plan_many_dft` I can do transforms along x,y and y,z axis:

```cpp
vector<complex<float_type>> yz_fft(vector<complex<float_type>> input, int N_X, int N_Y, int N_Z){
    vector<complex<float_type>> result(input.size());
    int rank = 2;
    int n[] = {N_Y,N_Z};
    int *inembed = n;
    int *onembed = n;
    int istride = 1;
    int ostride = 1;
    int idist = N_Y*N_Z;
    int odist = N_Y*N_Z;
    int howmany = N_X;
    fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_many_dft(
            rank,
            n,
            howmany,
            reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex *>(input.data()),
            inembed,
            istride,
            idist,
            reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex *>(result.data()),
            onembed,
            ostride,
            odist,
            FFTW_FORWARD,
            FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan);
    return result;
}

vector<complex<float_type>> xy_fft(vector<complex<float_type>> input, int N_X, int N_Y, int N_Z){
    vector<complex<float_type>> result(input.size());
    int rank = 2;
    int n[] = {N_X,N_Y};
    int *inembed = n;
    int *onembed = n;
    int istride = N_Z;
    int ostride = N_Z;
    int idist = 1;
    int odist = 1;
    int howmany = N_Z;
    fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_many_dft(
            rank,
            n,
            howmany,
            reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex *>(input.data()),
            inembed,
            istride,
            idist,
            reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex *>(result.data()),
            onembed,
            ostride,
            odist,
            FFTW_FORWARD,
            FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan);
    return result;
}
```

but I can't figure out how to do x,z transform. How do I do this?

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You can remove also c++ tag or put back c and add fortran. You can use FFTW with many languages and I don't care in which the answer will be

Comment: I think the simplest approach would be to do the 1D transform along x, then another along z. So you need to create two plans, and execute them in sequence.

Comment: @CrisLuengo and the best in terms of performance? Is there some way to use the fftw_plan_many_dft to do that? Or maybe I should rewrite data to place x and z axis differently in memory?

Comment: I don’t think it matters at all in terms of performance. You’re still planning an FFT for two dimensions under the hood, and applying the same number of 1D FFTs under the hood. Any sort of overhead from function calls is peanuts compared to the computational cost of the FFT. Note that plan_many_dft is a convenience function!

Comment: @CrisLuengo: FFT implementations may benefit in various ways, including cache locality and reduced data manipulation, from performing two FFTs at the same time, so I would not expect two separately planned FFTs to perform as well as one joint-planned FFT.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't see a huge difference in time between my own code that uses individual 1D FFTs from FFTW (I iterate over the array in my own code) vs. using the full nD FFT from FFTW as a single plan.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Did you test with all sizes? With all strides and embeddings? With all target configurations, including cache geometries? There are cases that may benefit from doing multiple operations at once and cases that may not. (And there may also be missed opportunities for optimization in FFTW.)

Comment: @czajah: It has been years since I used FFTW, so I am not familiar with the parameters anymore. Using the x-z axes instead of x-y and y-z should just be a matter of changing the geometry information, including the strides, distances, and sizes. You should provide an [mre] that includes the working x-y and y-z cases, a working cases that does the x and z transformations separately, and an attempt at the x-z case that can be compared to the implementation of doing them separately.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No, I did not test with all possible sizes and all possible configurations. I just did a sanity check to make sure I wasn't being stupid. I don't see how, in a multi-dimensional FFT, you can do any operations simultaneously, especially across dimensions. Maybe for a 2x2 FFT it is faster to compute the 2D FFT rather than individual 1D FFTs, but for more realistic sizes it makes no sense to do anything other than 1D FFTs along one dimension, then 1D FFTs along another dimension.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `fftw_plan_many_dft` requires the dimensions to be transformed to be contiguous. There is only one stride used to index elements in the nD array to be transformed. I thought maybe the guru interface allows for more complex layout, but I haven't found a way to do this with one plan.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Among other things, the bit-reversal permutations in the multiple FFTs can be consolidated.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh, interesting! I've never seen that done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there is a way to use `fftw_plan_many_dft` to do xz transform. Downvotes may suggest that people are not interested in that but I decided to share it anyway. For solutnion check `struct xz_fft_many` below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <complex>
#include <fftw3.h>

#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>


using namespace std;

using float_type = double;
using index_type = unsigned long;

vector<complex<float_type>> get_data(index_type N){

    std::vector<complex<float_type>> data(N);
    iota(data.begin(), data.end(),0);

    return data;
}

void print(vector<complex<float_type>> data,index_type N_X,index_type N_Y,index_type N_Z){
    for(int i=0; i!=N_X; ++i){
        for(int j=0; j!=N_Y; ++j){
            for(int k=0; k!=N_Z; ++k){
                index_type idx = i*(N_Y*N_Z)+j*N_Z+k;
                cout<<"[ "<<i<<", "<<j<<", "<<k<<" ] = "<<data.data()[idx]<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

struct x_fft {
    vector<complex<float_type>>& data;
    vector<complex<float_type>> result;
    fftw_plan fft_plan;
    index_type N_X;
    index_type N_Y;
    index_type N_Z;


    x_fft(vector<complex<float_type>>& data,index_type N_X,index_type N_Y,index_type N_Z)
            : data(data), N_X(N_X), N_Y(N_Y), N_Z(N_Z)
    {
        result = vector<complex<float_type>>(data.size());
        int rank = 1;
        int n[] = {(int)N_X};
        int *inembed = n;
        int *onembed = n;
        int istride = N_Y*N_Z;
        int ostride = istride;
        int idist = 1;
        int odist = idist;
        int howmany = N_Y*N_Z;
        fft_plan = fftw_plan_many_dft(
                rank,
                n,
                howmany,
                reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex *>(data.data()),
                inembed,
                istride,
                idist,
                reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex *>(result.data()),
                onembed,
                ostride,
                odist,
                FFTW_FORWARD,
                FFTW_MEASURE);
    }

    const vector<complex<float_type>> &getResult() const {
        return result;
    }

    vector<complex<float_type>>& run(){
        fftw_execute(fft_plan);
        return result;
    }

};

struct z_fft {
    vector<complex<float_type>>& data;
    vector<complex<float_type>> result;
    fftw_plan fft_plan;
    index_type N_X;
    index_type N_Y;
    index_type N_Z;


    z_fft(vector<complex<float_type>>& data,index_type N_X,index_type N_Y,index_type N_Z)
            : data(data), N_X(N_X), N_Y(N_Y), N_Z(N_Z)
    {
        result = vector<complex<float_type>>(data.size());
        int rank = 1;
        int n[] = {(int)N_Z};
        int *inembed = n;
        int *onembed = n;
        int istride = 1;
        int ostride = istride;
        int idist = N_Z;
        int odist = idist;
        int howmany = N_X*N_Y;
        fft_plan = fftw_plan_many_dft(
                rank,
                n,
                howmany,
                reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex *>(data.data()),
                inembed,
                istride,
                idist,
                reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex *>(result.data()),
                onembed,
                ostride,
                odist,
                FFTW_FORWARD,
                FFTW_MEASURE);
    }

    vector<complex<float_type>>& run(){
        fftw_execute(fft_plan);
        return result;
    }

};


struct xz_fft_many {
    vector<complex<float_type>>& data;
    vector<complex<float_type>> result;
    fftw_plan fft_plan;
    index_type N_X;
    index_type N_Y;
    index_type N_Z;


    xz_fft_many(vector<complex<float_type>>& data,index_type N_X,index_type N_Y,index_type N_Z)
            : data(data), N_X(N_X), N_Y(N_Y), N_Z(N_Z)
    {
        result = vector<complex<float_type>>(data.size());
        int rank = 2;
        int n[] = {(int) N_X, (int) N_Z};
        int inembed[] = {(int) N_X, (int) (N_Z*N_Y)};
        int *onembed = inembed;
        int istride = 1;
        int ostride = 1;
        int idist = N_Z;
        int odist = N_Z;
        int howmany = N_Y;
        fft_plan = fftw_plan_many_dft(
                rank,
                n,
                howmany,
                reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex *>(data.data()),
                inembed,
                istride,
                idist,
                reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex *>(result.data()),
                onembed,
                ostride,
                odist,
                FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_MEASURE);
    }

    vector<complex<float_type>>& run(){
        fftw_execute(fft_plan);
        return result;
    }

};

struct xz_fft_composition {
    vector<complex<float_type>>& data;
    index_type N_X;
    index_type N_Y;
    index_type N_Z;
    x_fft* xFft;
    z_fft* zFft;


    xz_fft_composition(vector<complex<float_type>>& data,index_type N_X,index_type N_Y,index_type N_Z)
            : data(data), N_X(N_X), N_Y(N_Y), N_Z(N_Z)
    {
        xFft = new x_fft(data,N_X,N_Y,N_Z);
        zFft = new z_fft(xFft->result,N_X,N_Y,N_Z);
    }

    vector<complex<float_type>>& run(){
        xFft->run();
        return zFft->run();
    }

};

struct TestData{
    index_type N_X = 512;
    index_type N_Y = 16;
    index_type N_Z = 16;

    index_type ARRAY_SIZE = N_X * N_Y * N_Z;
    std::vector<complex<float_type>> data = get_data(ARRAY_SIZE);

    TestData() {
//        print(data,N_X,N_Y,N_Z);
    }
};

TestData testData;

struct SanityTest{
    SanityTest() {
        xz_fft_many fft_many(testData.data, testData.N_X, testData.N_Y, testData.N_Z);
        xz_fft_composition fft_composition(testData.data, testData.N_X, testData.N_Y, testData.N_Z);
        std::vector<complex<float_type>> fft_many_result =  fft_many.run();
        std::vector<complex<float_type>> fft_composition_result =  fft_composition.run();

        bool equal = std::equal(fft_composition_result.begin(), fft_composition_result.end(), fft_many_result.begin());
        assert(equal);
        if(equal){
            cout << "ok" << endl;
        }
    }
};

SanityTest sanityTest;

static void XZ_test_many(benchmark::State& state) {
    xz_fft_many fft(testData.data, testData.N_X, testData.N_Y, testData.N_Z);
    for (auto _ : state) {
        auto result = fft.run();
    }
}

static void XZ_test_composition(benchmark::State& state) {
    xz_fft_composition fft(testData.data, testData.N_X, testData.N_Y, testData.N_Z);
    for (auto _ : state) {
        auto result = fft.run();
    }
}

BENCHMARK(XZ_test_many)->Iterations(1000);
BENCHMARK(XZ_test_composition)->Iterations(1000);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

If I done benchmarks correctly there are some significant differences beetwen `fftw_plan_many_dft` and *composition* approaches for different N_X, N_Y, N_Z combinations. For example using

```
    index_type N_X = 512;
    index_type N_Y = 16;
    index_type N_Z = 16;
```

I've got almost two times difference in favour of `fftw_plan_many_dft` but for other sets of input parameters I've often found *composition* aproach to be faster but not that much.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                                    Time             CPU   Iterations
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XZ_test_many/iterations:1000           1412647 ns      1364813 ns         1000
XZ_test_composition/iterations:1000    2619807 ns      2542472 ns         1000
```